# ssh: Warning despite disabling strict host key checking

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am running an `ansible` task but this is more of an `ssh` issue;

I execute an `rsync` command (from my `localhost` to a `vagrant` machine) as follows:

```
command: "rsync -zaP  -e 'ssh -p {{ ansible_port }} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' {{ temp_build_directory }}/artifacts.tar.gz {{ rsync_remote_user }}@{{ ansible_host }}:/tmp"
```

Despite the fact that I am explicitly disabling host key checking, at some point I got the following error:

```
TASK [send_artifacts : Transfer Artifacts -->  Transfer tarball to deployment targets] ***
fatal: [vagrant -> localhost]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd:
  - rsync
  - -zaP
  - -e
  - ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
  - /tmp/mdr-700263/artifacts.tar.gz
  - vagrant@127.0.0.1:/tmp
  delta: '0:00:00.351747'
  end: '2018-10-18 12:04:52.350948'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 23
  start: '2018-10-18 12:04:51.999201'
  stderr: |-
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    @    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
    @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
    IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
    Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
    It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
    The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
    SHA256:8r8mZHkCiXJBAu7LeaFsjpa5g2gpQTZzf7RpesOV0QQ.
    Please contact your system administrator.
    Add correct host key in /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
    Offending ECDSA key in /home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts:3
      remove with:
      ssh-keygen -f "/home/ansible/.ssh/known_hosts" -R [127.0.0.1]:2222
    Password authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
    Keyboard-interactive authentication is disabled to avoid man-in-the-middle attacks.
    rsync: link_stat "/tmp/mdr-700263/artifacts.tar.gz" failed: No such file or directory (2)
    rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
  stderr_lines:
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a *warning* from `ssh` about the change in host keys.  The *error* comes from `rsync` and says that the source file (`/tmp/mdr-700263/artifacts.tar.gz`) can not be found on the local machine.  These are likely not related.

You get the `ssh` warning since a verification of the host key against the known key in `known_hosts` is always done, regardless of the `StrictHostKeyChecking` setting.

From the `ssh_config` manual:

> `StrictHostKeyChecking`
>
> [...] If this flag
>           is set to “no” or “off”, ssh will automatically add new host keys
>           to the user known hosts files and allow connections to hosts with
>           changed hostkeys to proceed, subject to some restrictions.   [...] The host
>           keys of known hosts will be verified automatically in all cases.